# Comparator of generic class in Java

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I would like the following thing to work:  I have a generic class `public class TypeType<T1,T2>` that has two fields `public T1 t1` and `public T2 t2`.  I would like to write two `public static Comparator` methods for this class, `compareFirst()` and `compareSecond()`.  I would like the first method to compare only based on the `t1`s, and the second only based on the `t2`s.  The first method produces valid output *if* `T1 implements Comparable<T1>` and the second *if* `T2 implements Comparable<T2>`.

Is something like this possible?  Is there a way to check that `T1` and `T2` implement `Comparable`?  If not, can I still make this work?  (This class is only for internal usage.)

Thanks a bunch!

```
public class TypeType<T1,T2> {

    public T1 t1;
    public T2 t2;

    public TypeType() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public TypeType(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    /*
     * I know that the following does not work.
     * This is just pseudo-code for what I would like to achieve.
     */
    public static Comparator<TypeType<?,?>> comparatorFirst() {
        return new Comparator<TypeType<?,?>> {
            public int compare(TypeType<?,?> tt1, TypeType<?,?> tt2) {
                return tt1.t1.compareTo(tt2.t1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

In case interesting to others:  I ended up implementing @pbabcdefp's Java 8 solution using Lambda Expressions.

```
public static <T1 extends Comparable<? super T1>> Comparator<TypeType<T1,?>> compareOne() {
    return (tt1, tt2) -> tt1.t1.compareTo(tt2.t1);
}

public static <T2 extends Comparable<? super T2>> Comparator<TypeType<?,T2>> compareTwo() {
    return (tt1, tt2) -> tt1.t2.compareTo(tt2.t2);
}

public static <T1 extends Comparable<? super T1>,T2 extends Comparable<? super T2>> Comparator<TypeType<T1,T2>> compareOneThenTwo() {
    return (tt1, tt2) -> {
        if ( tt1.t1.equals(tt2.t1) )
            return tt1.t2.compareTo(tt2.t2);
        else
            return tt1.t1.compareTo(tt2.t1);
    };
}

public static <T1 extends Comparable<? super T1>,T2 extends Comparable<? super T2>> Comparator<TypeType<T1,T2>> compareTwoThenOne() {
    return (tt1, tt2) -> {
        if ( tt1.t2.equals(tt2.t2) )
            return tt1.t1.compareTo(tt2.t1);
        else
            return tt1.t2.compareTo(tt2.t2);
    };
}
```

Comment: the return type would something like `Comparator<TypeType<T extends Comparable<T>,?>>`

Comment: Do you need to be the generic objects always to have Comparable implemented or do you need it with both cases?
Technically you dont need the generics, if you want it to be `Comparable` objects just ask for the interface in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several good answers here, but note that with Java 8 you can return a lambda.

```
public static <T1 extends Comparable<? super T1>> Comparator<TypeType<T1,?>> comparatorFirst() {
    return (tt1, tt2) -> tt1.t1.compareTo(tt2.t1);
}

public static <T2 extends Comparable<? super T2>> Comparator<TypeType<?, T2>> comparatorSecond() {
    return (tt1, tt2) -> tt1.t2.compareTo(tt2.t2);
}
```

Comment: This looks very sleek, I like it a lot.  Thank you!

Comment: I'd actually recommend something even simpler -- static import `Comparator.comparing`, and write `comparing(tt -> tt.t1)` for the first version, and `comparing(tt -> tt.t2)` for the second.

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` operator can be used both to see if a specific class is derived from a class or if a class implements a specific interface.

i.e. `t1 instanceof Comparable` would return `true` if it implements `Comparable`.

Just be aware that generics don't exist at runtime, so you can only check if implements `Comparable`, not that it implements `Comparable<T1>`.

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```
public static <U1 extends Comparable<? super U1>, U2 extends Comparable<? super U2>> Comparator<TypeType<U1, U2>> compareFirst() {
  return new Comparator<TypeType<U1, U2>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(TypeType<U1, U2> o1, TypeType<U1, U2> o2) {
      return o1.t1.compareTo(o2.t1);
    }

  };
}
```

Please note that you won't be able to create a comparator with `TypeType` instances that are not parameterized with types that don't extend `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Comparator<TypeType<T1 extends Comparable<T1>,T1 extends Comparable<T2>>> comparatorFirst() {
    return new Comparator<> {
        public int compare(TypeType<T1,T2> tt1, TypeType<T1,T2> tt2) {
            return tt1.t1.compareTo(tt2.t1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following class definition to enforce that both `T1` and `T2` implement `Comparable`, so you don't have to check it at runtime:

```
public class TypeType<T1 extends Comparable<T1>, T2 extends Comparable<T2>> {
...
}
```